# Equal height columns and vertical align image in column?

Tags: css

Was wondering if anyone can show me best way to vertically align my image in image col and have the column equal in height to the text col?

**CSS**

```
*{padding:0;margin:0;}

.col{
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
}

.col-text {
    background: silver;
}

.col-img {
    background: red;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
}

.col-img img {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.cf:after{
        content:"";
        display:table;
        clear:both;
    }
}
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LUpmG/1/

Comment: What do you mean, "vertically align"?  Push to the top, to the bottom, middle, or stretch?

Comment: @punund yeah vertically align the image in the middle of the equal height column?

Answer (score 2):

This is my version: http://jsfiddle.net/LUpmG/2/

In short, you need to get rid of floats, use `display: table-cell`, and apply `vertical-align: middle` to the container.